# Turning related Comma Separated strings into individual rows with multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Previously someone asked about [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows). This works great for one column, but I have an extension question. What if I want to split two (or more) related columns. That is, if I have data like this (using the data from the previous post as a base):

```
| SomeID         | OtherID     | Data      | RelatedData |
+----------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| abcdef-.....   | cdef123-... | 18,20,22  | xxx,,yyy    |
| abcdef-.....   | 4554a24-... | 17,19     | a,bb        |
| 987654-.....   | 12324a2-... | 13,19,20  | r,s,t       |
```

And want to return rows like the following:

```
| SomeID         | OtherID     | Data | RelatedData |
+----------------+-------------+------+-------------+
| abcdef-.....   | cdef123-... | 18   | xxx         |
| abcdef-.....   | cdef123-... | 20   |             |
| abcdef-.....   | cdef123-... | 22   | yyy         |
| abcdef-.....   | 4554a24-... | 17   | a           |
| abcdef-.....   | 4554a24-... | 19   | bb          |
| ...            | ...         | ...  | ...         |
```

I was hoping to use STRING_SPLIT due to its simplicity, but I cannot find a way to make it work. This does not work:

```
select OtherID, cs1.Value, cs2.Value
from yourtable
cross apply STRING_SPLIT (Data, ',') cs1
cross apply STRING_SPLIT (RelatedData, ',') cs2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()`, `JOIN`, then `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: Time to redesign the database--this is the real answer.

Comment: Alternatively, if people can't be persuaded to normalize their data, consider JSON. Storing related data together would, at least, greatly simplify these issues. Hopping across "related" columns is very inconvenient no matter how you slice it.

Comment: I am trying to move data from a very bizarre format (Unidata with multi-valued fields) into a normalized database. Not an easy transition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the comments regarding this design. It would be better to normalize your data.

To do this with `string_split()` you can use the `row_number()` workaround for an ordinal like so:

```
;with cs1 as (
  select SomeId, OtherId, x.Value
    , ItemNumber = row_number() over (partition by t.SomeId, t.OtherId order by (Select Null))
  from t
    cross apply string_split(Data,',') x
)
, cs2 as (
  select SomeId, OtherId, x.Value
    , ItemNumber = row_number() over (partition by t.SomeId, t.OtherId order by (Select Null))
  from t
    cross apply string_split(RelatedData,',') x
)
select cs1.SomeId, cs1.OtherId, cs1.Value, cs2.Value
from cs1 
  inner join cs2
    on cs1.SomeId = cs2.SomeId
   and cs1.OtherId = cs2.OtherId
   and cs1.ItemNumber = cs2.ItemNumber
```

[dbfiddle.uk demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=48fd9895e8ca790d33a5028790b50558)

returns:

```
+--------------+-------------+-------+-------+
|    SomeId    |   OtherId   | Value | Value |
+--------------+-------------+-------+-------+
| 987654-..... | 12324a2-... |    13 | r     |
| 987654-..... | 12324a2-... |    19 | s     |
| 987654-..... | 12324a2-... |    20 | t     |
| abcdef-..... | 4554a24-... |    17 | a     |
| abcdef-..... | 4554a24-... |    19 | bb    |
| abcdef-..... | cdef123-... |    18 | xxx   |
| abcdef-..... | cdef123-... |    20 |       |
| abcdef-..... | cdef123-... |    22 | yyy   |
+--------------+-------------+-------+-------+
```

---

I think it is simpler to use a custom function that includes an ordinal. For example, the delimited split inline table valued function by Jeff Moden:

```
select SomeId, OtherId, cs1.Item, cs2.Item
from t
  cross apply dbo.delimitedsplit8K(Data,',') cs1
  cross apply dbo.delimitedsplit8K(RelatedData,',') cs2
where cs1.ItemNumber = cs2.ItemNumber
```

returns the same results.

---

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)
- [Ordinal workaround for **`string_split()**` - Solomon Rutzky](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/2433171)

Comment: This worked like a charm. I tried both, and do like the second version as it is much cleaner. Thanks!